# Render text on screen with MCP in Minecraft 1.18

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge, mcps

I want to display a text on the screen in Minecraft 1.18 with MCP-Reborn. I have watched tutorials on YouTube but they only cover how to do it in 1.12, after around 4 hours of searching the internet I didn't find anything for 1.18. In 1.12 they used `Minecraft.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj.drawString(text, x, y, color);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah there is like no documentation on mcp reborn :/

But to display text you can use:

```
Minecraft.getInstance().font.draw(poseStack, "Your text", x, y, color);
```

PoseStack is only in the newer minecraft code so i previously never heard of it. If you draw the text in a gui with the render method (in previous versions called drawScreen) you can just use the passed PoseStack, else i would probably just create a new instance, works aswell.

x, y and color are the same as in 1.8 and 1.12

font is pretty much the new fontrendererobj

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem with MCP is that it only works for **1.7.10**, **1.8.8**, **1.9.4**, **1.10**, **1.11.2** and **1.12** as we can see in their [download page](http://www.modcoderpack.com/). That's probably why no one covers how to do it pass those versions.

However, you could use [MCP-Reborn](https://github.com/Hexeption/MCP-Reborn), it might be helpful!

Comment: I'm using MCP-Reborn but it's hard to find a documentation or examples for it.